# Determinar bairro a partir da Latitude e Longitude

Tags: google-maps, geolocalização, google-maps-api-3

Estou usando o **Google Maps API V3** mais especificamente **angular-google-maps**. Preciso exibir o ponto exato do usuário no momento em que abre o mapa e também exibir todas as pessoas que podem estar naquele bairro(estando ou não naquele momento). O problema é como definir o bairro que usuário está apenas com a latitude e a longitude e a partir desse momento listar as pessoas que podem estar no bairro? Pois os *markers* podem trazer n+1 marcas próximas, sendo que as vezes não possui bairro, como:

- "Terceira Avenida, 6 - Brasília, DF, Brasil"
- "Brasília - DF, Brasil"
- "Distrito Federal, Brasil"

Pensei em buscar pelo CEP, mas o "postal_code" também não é constante, as vezes retorna outras não. Lendo no **Stackoverflow** em EN foi dito que precisa do nome da rua, mas aqui em Brasília mesmo com a rua não é retornado o CEP.

Não é possível forçar retorno do CEP e assim definir o bairro.

Pensei em alguma API que delimita os bairro e quando a Lat/Long estiver dentro do perímetro conseguiria retornar o bairro/cep.

Enfim não encontrei nenhuma solução ou caminho que possa seguir.